# Sparse Cholesky decomposition of factorized matrix

Tags: computational-mathematics, least-squares, sparse-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

I want the diagonal of a matrix $Y^TA^{-1}Y$ where $A=X^TX$ and $X$ is very sparse with dimensions ~1e6 x ~1e5 (so $A$ is 1e5 by 1e5). $Y$ is something like 1e5 by 1e4 (also sparse). Currently I'm explicitly calculating $A$ then getting its Cholesky decomposition $LL^T$ via `sksparse.cholmod` which exploits its sparsity in $A$ nicely. Then I can `solve(L,Y)` and get my diagonal terms.

However, I feel like I should be able to do something with $X$ directly, e.g. if I had a QR decomposition $X=QR$ then I would have $A = R^T Q^T Q R = R^T R$. This would presumably save me some computation by avoiding the explicit calculation of $A$, but there don't seem to sparse QR methods widely available (https://github.com/yig/PySPQR fails to compile for me): I'm limited to Python since this is part of a package.

Is there some more straightforward approach I'm missing (e.g. via least squares)?

(also please let me know if another stackexchange like https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate)

Answer (score 3):

You'll find the LSQR as an option for solving large sparse linear systems that max be over or under determined. This is included in `scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr`.
However, this solver doesn't seem applicable at for your case (unless your $Y$ has a deeper story, like $Y=X^T b$?). Iterative solvers wouldn't be my pick for solving 1e4 RHS' regardless.

Note that your $A$ has the major advantage of being 10 times smaller than $X$, and the factorization of sparse systems aren't necessarily themselves (very) sparse. Computing $A$ is basically free compared to everything else we need to solve here.
There is possibly some deeper cleverness beyond me that might be found here but I suspect the boring answer that you aren't going to do a lot better than what you already do.

Comment: Thanks - I was feeling like there should be a connection to least squares I could leverage but seems it doesn't quite work out.